# geom_vline on R not working for adding vertical line on a ggplot graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, line

I'm having a problem to draw a graph with multiple lines on R.
I'm trying to add some vertical lines on a plot, but it's not working.

I'm using the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library("ggthemes")
library("scales")
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016"),
                levels=c("2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016")),
  #frequency = c(3, 8, 20, 26, 30, 38,29, 27, 13, 1)
  frequency = c(3, 8, 22, 29, 29, 37, 29, 33, 19, 30),
  frequency_performance = c(3, 7, 20, 22, 19, 29, 18, 15, 16, 18),
  frequency_correctness = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 5, 9, 1, 4),
  frequency_fault = c(0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time)) + #, y=frequency, group=1)) + 
   theme(aspect.ratio=.4,text = element_text(size=13), 
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"), 
          panel.border = element_rect( fill = NA), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency, colour="slateblue"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_performance, colour="darkgoldenrod"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_correctness, colour="darkgreen"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_fault, colour="chocolate"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of publications") + # Set axis labels
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Category", labels = c("Fault tolerance", "Performance", "Correctness", "All papers")) +
  ggtitle("")

p +   geom_vline(xintercept=c(2010,2012,2014,2016), linetype="dotted", color="red")
```

I tried using another format with this code, but it also didn't worked.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016"),
                levels=c("2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016")),
  frequency = c(3, 8, 22, 29, 29, 37, 29, 33, 19, 30, 3, 7, 20, 22, 19, 29, 18, 15, 16, 18, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 5, 9, 1, 4, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8),
  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
)

p<- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=frequency,group=group, color=as.factor(group) )) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                     values=c("slateblue", "darkgoldenrod", "darkgreen", "chocolate")) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of publications") + theme_bw() + 

guides(shape = FALSE, linetype = FALSE,
       colour = guide_legend(override.aes =  list(shape = c(16, 16, 16,  16),
                                                  linetype = c("solid","solid","solid", "solid"),
                                                  labels= c("All articles","Performance","Correctness","Fault tolerance"),
                                                  title = "Category"
       )))

p +   geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(2012), linetype="dotted", color="red", size=3)
```

There are other problems that I have with both codes (that's why I have two different codes), like not being able to order the legend on the first code, or the color is wrong for some reason. The second graph I can't replace the legend text for some reason, but the vertical line is the main problem right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the way you created the `time` column from `factor` to `numeric` as follows.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = 2007:2016,
  #frequency = c(3, 8, 20, 26, 30, 38,29, 27, 13, 1)
  frequency = c(3, 8, 22, 29, 29, 37, 29, 33, 19, 30),
  frequency_performance = c(3, 7, 20, 22, 19, 29, 18, 15, 16, 18),
  frequency_correctness = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 5, 9, 1, 4),
  frequency_fault = c(0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7, 2, 8)
)
```

Now it works. In the following code I also change the line size to `2` for clarity.

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time)) + #, y=frequency, group=1)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=.4,text = element_text(size=13), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"), 
        panel.border = element_rect( fill = NA), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency, colour="slateblue"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_performance, colour="darkgoldenrod"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_correctness, colour="darkgreen"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=frequency_fault, colour="chocolate"),group=1, size=1.5) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of publications") + # Set axis labels
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Category", labels = c("Fault tolerance", "Performance", "Correctness", "All papers")) +
  ggtitle("")

p +   geom_vline(xintercept=c(2010,2012,2014,2016), 
                 linetype="dotted", 
                 color="red",
                 size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: @Dante003 I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

```
p +   geom_vline(xintercept=which(dat$time %in% c('2010', '2012', '2014', '2016')), linetype="dotted", color="red")
```

Comment: While this may provide an answer to the question, it'd be good if you can add a little text explaining it, instead of leaving a block of plain code.